# Get rid of "Please wait..." string while using blockUI

Tags: jquery-ui, blockui

I am using the dialog

```
$("#xDialog").dialog({width: 700, position: 'top' });
```

and wanted to block user activity for the page when the above dialog pops up. So i use blockUI

like

```
$.blockUI();
```

It does dims the background but i get a additional dialog with a string "Please wait..." is there a way to get rid of that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '' });
```

P.S. - Taken from the BlockUI docs [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).